# יהי רצון שיהיה לרפואה on optional pills

Tags: medicine, psych-mentalhealth

Many say יהי רצון שיהיה לרפואה before taking pills and other forms of medicine:

> Flavorless medicine, such as pills that you swallow, do not require a blessing—but we do say a prayer that the medicine should be efficacious:
>
> יהי רצון שיהיה לרפואה
>
> "May it be Your will that this medicine shall bring healing."3
>
> ([link](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/654197/jewish/Do-I-recite-a-blessing-before-taking-oral-medication.htm))

Would this Yehi Ratzon apply to optional pills that *do* help the body, but are not required (by any means)? This would include growth medications, pain relievers, vitamin supplements, etc.

Comment: Close as opinion based? You can pray for whatever you want whenever you want. What exactly could someone answer here?

Comment: @DoubleAA the source in the question implies that there's a specific requirement or it's-an-especially-good-thing to pray when taking medication, and the asker here is clearly asking whether that applies to certain pills.